# Hardware occlusion query result seems not accurate

Tags: opengl, 3d, occlusion

I came across an issue about occlusion query. In my case, the query result seems always larger than it is supposed to be. e.g. i use a 1024*1024 resolution for rendering, but the query result of an object in the scene is 2085029(>1024*1024).

The query method used is from **GPU Gems** [Chapter 29](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_ch29.html)

```
        glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
        glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, occlusionQuery[0]);

        mesh->Render();

        glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);
        glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
        glGetQueryObjectuiv(occlusionQuery[0], GL_QUERY_RESULT, &screenFragmentCount[0]);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

The [occlusion query](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Occlusion_Query) does not tell you how many pixels passed the tests. It tells you how many *fragments* passed the tests (or more accurately, "samples").

If you draw one triangle, and then draw a triangle in front of it, the occlusion query counts fragments from both, even though the earlier triangles are occluded by the later ones. The triangles are rasterized in-order. So the later triangle that covers the earlier one has not been rasterized by the time the occlusion query count is bumped. Self-occlusion like this is only counted if triangles are rendered from nearest to farthest.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I mixed up ‘pixels’ and 'samples'. So in order to get the pixel count of an object, What should i do? Are there any similar query methods?    ;)